# Redirect to https after ensuring ssl availability

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, ssl

I'm using this code to redirect

```
  If Not Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Dim url As String = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:")
        Response.Redirect(url)
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Now i want to redirect to HTTPS only if ssl available on my website.
So how to check ssl availability?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101414/verify-remote-ssl-certificate-during-https-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using function created at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378470/2012977 can help check availability of url. See example below.

```
public bool UrlExists(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Method = "HEAD"; 

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```